# Hyperparameter Tuning with custom ML method

Tags: python, cross-validation

I am implementing a custom class of ML methods which is a combination of Lasso and Random Forest it goes as following:

1. I fit lasso on my data with some lambda
2. I run Random Forest on the residuals of the Lasso predictions with some hyperparameters
3. Forecast of the model is equal to sum of predictions from step 1 and 2
4. use time-series cross validation (sliding window) to tune parameters for both Lasso and RF simultaneously

I have trouble designing the Grid search for this algorithm, is there a tool in python that I can use to tune parameters easily, without coding whole thing myself?

---

Code for the method in current state, where cross validation happens locally, separately for RF and Lasso, my goal is have a global grid-search for both methods together:

```
lasso_cv = Lasso(fit_intercept=True, normalize=False)
    tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)
    b = np.linspace(-10, 10, 50)
    b = b.tolist()
    lasso_params = {'alpha': b}
    grid = GridSearchCV(lasso_cv, lasso_params, cv=tscv,
                        refit=True,
                        n_jobs=-1)

    grid.fit(X_train, Y_train.ravel())
    errors = grid.best_estimator_.predict(X_train)
    errors = Y_train - errors.reshape(-1,1)
    rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1234)
    param_search = {"max_depth": [10, None],
                    "n_estimators": [100, 500],
                    "max_features": ['auto', 10]
                    }
    grid1 = GridSearchCV(rf, param_search, cv=tscv,
                       refit=True,
                       n_jobs=-1)
    grid1.fit(X_train, errors.ravel())

    p = X.tail(1).to_numpy()
    p = pd.DataFrame(p).to_numpy()
    pred = grid.best_estimator_.predict(p.reshape(1, -1)) + grid1.best_estimator_.predict(p.reshape(1, -1))
```

Comment: have you looked at [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html)?

Comment: Why don't you encapsulate lasso and random forest within a class? If that class follows sklearn's guidelines about extending the Classifier class, GridSearchCV should work.